# Propagating checked exceptions for an AutoClosable wrapper

Tags: java, generics, checked-exceptions

Is there a way to declare a method in a generic type that wraps another method for another type and declares the same thrown exceptions? The most common example I can think of for this would be `AutoClosable`.

```
public class LazyReference<T extends AutoClosable> implements AutoClosable{
    public LazyReference(Supplier<T> factory){ ... }
    public T get() { ... } //get the instance for this. Create one from factory if needed
    @Override
    public void close() throws ????? { instance.close(); }
}
```

Is there a way to implement that such that the wrapper `close()` would throw the same (one or more) checked exceptions that `T` throws when `T::close()` is called?